# Maximal ideals in the ring of measurable functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, ring-theory

The $R$ ring of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ has a property that its maximal  look like a subset of $R$ consisting of those functions which vanish at a common single point in $[0,1]$.

**Question:** Let $S$ be the ring of all the measurable functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. How maximal ideals look like in this ring?

Comment: See here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122237/maximal-ideals-of-the-algebra-of-measurable-functions